# Spring Data Rest - Parameters with default values

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have created the following `@RepositoryRestResource` query where I want to create a dynamic query for my rest api. So basically I would want to do something like:

```
myHost/myApp/data/search/all?name=me&age=20&address=myhome&etc=etc
```

So I have created the query below:

```
   @Query("Select t from Data t " +
            "where " +
            "t.name like :name AND " +
            "t.age = :age AND " +
            "t.address = :address AND " +
            "t.etc= :etc"
    @RestResource(path = "all", rel = "all")
    Page findByAll(@Param("name") String name, @Param("age") String age,
            @Param("address") String address, @Param("etc") String etc, Page page);
```

Obviously some of these may not have been entered. Is there some way to define default values on the Repository? So for example I would want `name` to have a default value of `%`.

I'm not entirely sure this approach is the correct one for what I want to do, so any alternative suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is older, but I had a similar issue and solved it as follows:

```
@Query("Select t from Data t " +
        "where " +
        "(:name IS NULL or t.name like :name) AND " +
        "(:age IS NULL or t.age = :age) AND " +
        "(:address IS NULL or t.address = :address) AND " +
        "(:etc IS NULL or t.etc= :etc)")
@RestResource(path = "all", rel = "all")
Page findByAll(@Param("name") String name, @Param("age") String age,
        @Param("address") String address, @Param("etc") String etc, Page page);
```

Comment: Note that with this technique you cannot use primitive datatype for parameters, use their wrapper object counter-part instead. E.g.: `Integer` and not `int`

Answer (score 2):

So, one possible solution might be that you might go to the controller and use in your `@Controller`/`@RestController` your `@RequestParam` with attributes `required = false`and `defaultValue = "%"`.

A corresponding call might look like this:

```
@RestController
...
@RequestMapping(value = "[myCallFromFrontend]", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseItem getItemsByFilters (
    @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "%") String name,
    @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "%") String age,
    @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "%") String address,
    @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "%") String etc,
    HttpServletResponse response){

    ResponseItem item = null;
    try {
         //you might do this in service layer.
         item = myRepository.findByAll(name, age, address, etc);
    } catch (myException mE) {
            log.error("...", mE);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return item;
    }
```

So now you got your default values set. I don't know a way to set them directly at repository-level, though. I created a question about that right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763155/spring-data-jpa-repositories-is-it-possible-to-give-the-params-a-default-value)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem, and as far as I could research, the best way for solving this is to make a different query for each set of values.