# Spring Data JPA Repositories: Is it possible to give the params a default Value / default all?

Tags: java, spring, orm, spring-data-jpa

So, in short terms: Is it possible to set a parameter to "default: All" or more generally to a default specific value in Spring Data JPA (possibly @Query-Annotated) Repository-Methods?

I'm [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25763169/1341599) that it's possible in (Rest)controllers to set a default Value, i'm just curious if it's possible to do it at Repository-Level, too. Might be a nice feature I think, for "get me some filtered resultSet where filters might be not set in frontend by a rest-call" is a very common use-case.

Example-Query:

```
@Query("select new com.my.dto(e.name, e.age, e.address)" +
        " from Entity e" +
        "where e.name like ?1 " +
        "and e.age like ?2  " +
        "and e.street like ?3")
List<Item> findItemsFiltered(String name, String age, String street);
```

So when let's say street is not set, the Repository should use "%" to return all Results where the other criteria is matching but the street is not relevant.

Comment: That would become messy imho. Instead you are probably better of with a `Specification` that constructs the dynamic query (which is what you basically want). See also http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: You also might want to check the reference guide -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: sounds like a viable solution, thanks so far :) I just thought for especially the common use-case "fall back to select everything if no value defined", there would be a somewhat "easier way to do this". Would be great to have something easy here, thinking about other queries having a List of filtervalues like `where e.group IN ?3` (you can't use "%" here). But well, thanks so far. If you want, create an answer out of your comment. I'll still wait for other answers, but as said, it _is_ a viable solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it in the `@Query` itself?
Something like:

```
@Query("select new com.my.dto(e.name, e.age, e.address)" +
    " from Entity e" +
    "where e.name like ?1 " +
    "and e.age like ?2  " +
    "and e.street like (CASE WHEN ?3 IS NULL THEN '%' ELSE ?3 END)")
List<Item> findItemsFiltered(String name, String age, String street);
```

Another way would be to have a custom parameter annotation like `@Default` but that would require customizing the repository implementation itself I believe.

Another alternative is the `Specification` as M. Deinum mentioned.